# Angular-UI-Router: Reserve query parameter on url

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

When I click a link in my email to my site, for example:

```
http://example.com/step1?code=1234
```

My code will appear in url, and then disappear immediately before enter my controller.

```
.state('step1', {
     url: '/step1?code',           
     templateUrl: templateDir + 'step1.html',           
     controller: 'Step1Controller'
})
```

Is there any method can I persist my query string and get it by `$stateParams`?

Comment: That looks correct to me. `$stateParams.code` should give you the value of the `code` query parameter. Are you using HTML5 mode in your app? i.e. do you have the `#` in your app URLs that you might be missing in your email?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
.state('step1', {
     url: '/step1/:code',           
     templateUrl: templateDir + 'step1.html',           
     controller: 'Step1Controller'
})
```

Comment: That isn't correct since that would look at a url of `http://example.com/step1/1234`